# SQLite - How to structure my data properly into SQL databases

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm doing a webapp in Python that scrapes shoes information and stores it into a database.

For example, the data scraped in my Python program for a single shoe would be:

```
model = 'Nike Tiempo XL'                      (string)
price = 45.0                                  (float)
sizes = ['9', '10','11.5','12','13','13.5']   (list of strings)
```

Now, how would I store the `sizes` variable into my database?

```
CREATE TABLE shoes(model TEXT, price INTEGER, sizes ?)
```

How would I approach this? I was thinking of creating another database and then joining them together but I can't get that idea into something more concrete.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you add another table. 
The first column is the primary key of the shoe and the second one is the size.

So if you then then Select the shoe you can get every size with a join.

If you want to get the details on how to write the sql queries leave a comment :)

Comment: Just to note, the size parameter is not a single value, it's a list containing all available sizes of that shoe.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Create table shoes(
 ShoeID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMERY KEY(),
 Model Nvarchar(50),
 Cost money
 )

 Create table sizes(
 SizeID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMERY KEY(),
 ShoeID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES shoes(ShoeID),
 Size int
 )
```